# Disable autocommit and rollback statments in Heidisql

Tags: mysql, rollback, heidisql, autocommit

How to disable autocommit in Heidisql? Also how to rollback update query? I am using version 9.3.0.
Using set autocommit = 0; does not work.

Comment: Using "set autocommit = 0" works if you do it correctly (e.g. if you do it in the same session as whatever query you want to execute) and if it is used on a table that supports transactions (e.g. it will not work on MyISAM-tables). So you will need to add more information about what you did (exactly) to identify why it does not work for you (or why it does not do what you expect).